Funcion con menor coste computacional, extracción de archivos en directorio
Esta funcion usa el metodo os.lisdir para tener la lista de archivos
def crear_carpetasYears2(pat):
       tiempo_inicial=t.time()
       archivitos=os.listdir(pat)
       years=[]
       for arch in archivitos:
        arc=str(t.strftime('%Y',t.gmtime(os.path.getctime(arch)))) 
        if len(years)==0:
           years.append(arc)
           print(arc)
        else:
           if arc not in years:
            print(arc)
            years.append(arc)
            
            #Ruta de las nuevas carpetas a crear
            #print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),arc[2:]))
       print(years)
       tiempo_final=t.time()
       print(tiempo_final-tiempo_inicial)
    

Mientras que esta lo hace con el metodo os.scandir
  def crear_carpetasYears(pat):
       tiempo_inicial=t.time()
       archivos=list()
       years=[]
       for arch in os.scandir(pat):
        arc=str(t.strftime('%Y',t.gmtime(os.path.getctime(arch.name))))
        archivos.append(arc)
        if len(years)==0:
           years.append(arc)
           print(arc)
           #os.mkdir(arc[2:])
        else:
           if arc not in years:
            print(arc)
            #os.mkdir(arc[2:])
            years.append(arc)
            
            #Ruta de las nuevas carpetas a crear
            #print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),arc[2:]))
       #print(m)
       #Lista de years
       print(years)
       tiempo_final=t.time()
       print(tiempo_final-tiempo_inicial)

Me preocupa el coste computacional siento que en la segunda funcion hago muchas llamadas al sistema con el metodo os.scandir por eso queria consultar cual de estas seria mejor

Según dice, scandir es más rápido. https://peps.python.org/pep-0471/

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Y porque no haces un profiling???
